Is there a notion of free energy that could apply to the Earth?
Is there a notion of free energy that could apply to a complex system with variations in temperature, such as the Earth?
Imagine the Earth were an isolated system (no Sun or Moon). The total number would add together the energies that can be extracted from bringing the winds and ocean currents to a stop, from equalizing the temperatures between the poles and the equator, from extracting the geothermal energy, from slowing its rotation to a stop, and radiating away heat until the Earth is an inert rock at the temperature of space. Adding together all these ways of extracting energy, it seems there should be some final number.
Gibbs free energy requires temperature and pressure to be constant, and furthermore requires the whole system to be at a single temperature T. The Earth is not a single temperature or pressure.
Helmholtz free energy requires temperature to be constant, not true for the Earth.
Is there a general notion of free energy that could apply to the whole Earth?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Neither Helmholtz free energy needs constant temperature nor Gibbs free energy needs constant temperature - constant pressure processes to be defined; these are state functions that are perfectly well defined for any system that can have  e.g., internal energy assigned to it. If the system has a thermodynamic "state" then it can have $U,F,G,...$ and any other number of state functions equally well-defined.

It is convenient to measure via external work between equilibrium states the change in state function called internal energy if the system is isolated, or to measure the change in Helmholtz free energy if the system is isothermal, but they exist whether or however you measure them or not.
